# C# - How to clear a ListBox's values

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How is it possible to clear a ListBox's values, e.g.

```
    private void clearvalues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        <Wipe ListBox1 Values>
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you're using WinForms

```
listBox.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
   listBox.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: And why in the world would you *ever* write the first block of code when you can use the second line? At best, you've shown these in the wrong order. But more likely, there's no reason to even discuss the first one. There are dozens of other ways to clear the items, but it's absolutely unnecessary to code them.

Answer (score -1):

Try This One

```
ListBox1.ClearSelection();
```